# Throws Specif Exception or handle Generic Exception contains error code

Tags: java, exception

I have one scenario where I need to find the subscriber based on his primay identity/ alternate identity.

Now There is may condition in which operation gets fail. like DBDown, Subscriber not found, primary identity not found for alternate identity etc.

Now to handle this scenario I have two option.

1. Create Specific Exceptions for each or group of failure scenarios.

   ```
   public class SubscriberFetchingFailedException extends Exception {

      public SubscriberFetchingFailedException(String message) {
        super(message);
      }
    }

   /**
    * throw when Primary identity not found against alternate identity
    */

    public class PrimaryIdentityNotFound extends SubscriberFetchingFailedException {
        public PrimaryIdentityNotFound(String message) {
           super(message);
        }
    }
   ```

you can compare with **IOException** and **FileNotFoundException**.

2. Create one Exception only and for each scenario, I provide an error code.

   ```
   public class SubscriberFetchingFailedException extends Exception {
       public SubscriberFetchingFailedException(String message, int errorCode) {
           super(message);
       }
   }
   ```

you can compare this with **SQLException**.

I have maximum 10 error scenario.

Now I want to know that which one is better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable, but you could try to combine both approaches. Try to group the errors into a general type of error and then you could provide specific error codes for that group. If the categories are similar enough, such as all of them are SQL errors then going with one group should be fine as long as you display appropriate error messages.